# What is the big-O complexity of the following pseudocode?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

What would be the computational complexity of the following **pseudocode**?

```
integer recursive (integer n) {
   if (n == 1)
      return (1);
   else
      return (recursive (n-1) + recursive (n-1));
}
```

In the real world, the calls would get optimized and yield **linear** complexity, but with the RAM model on which big-Oh is calculated, what would be the complexity? **2^n**?

Comment: The complexity as such seems to be 2^n, but it can be made to reduce to n.

Comment: Yes, this seems `2 ^ n`.

Comment: On every recursion, your recursion tree branches with a factor of two. So by the end of the recursion, you have a full binary tree with depth `n`, so the order would be `Θ(2^n)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity of this algorithm in its current form is indeed O(2<sup>n</sup>), because on each level of call, there will be twice more number of calls.

The first call (recursive(n)) constitutes one call

The next level (recursive(n-1)) constitutes 2 calls

At the base case (recursive(1)) it constitutes 2<sup>n-1</sup> calls.

So the total number of function calls is 1+2+…+2<sup>n-1</sup> = 2<sup>n</sup>-1

So the complexity is O(2<sup>n</sup>).

*Additional points:*

As you said, this can be easily made O(n) (or perhaps O(log n) for this special case using fast exponentiation) by memoization, or dynamic programming.

Answer (score 2):

Your complexity will be [image]

Why is it so? Simply [mathematical induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) proof:

- N=1: special case, count of steps = 1.
- N=2, Obvious, [image] = 2, so it's correct
- Let it be correct for `N=K`, i.e. for `N=K` it will be [image]
- Assuming `N=K+1`. The function `recursive` will call itself recursively for `N=K` two times: `recursive(K+1) = recursive(K) + recursive(K)` as it follows from the code. That is: [image]. So, for `N=K+1` we got [image] steps.

So we've proof that complexity for `N` will be [image] in common case (from definition of mathematical induction).